# What are `globals` and `locals` parameters in Python __import__ function for?

Tags: python, import

There's a part of [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) in Python documentation, which I don't understand:

> `__import__(name[, globals[, locals[, fromlist[, level]]]])`
>
> The function imports the module `name`, potentially using the given `globals` and `locals` to determine how to interpret the `name` in a package context. The standard implementation does not use its `locals` argument at all, and uses its `globals` only to determine the package context of the import statement.

What is there to "interpret" about the module name? What is package context?

An example call using those parameters looks like this:

```
spam = __import__('spam', globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

Why does the example provide `globals()` and `locals()` to the function? What happens when I only provide `globals()`? Or neither?

I am probably missing some part of the namespace logic with relation to importing modules. Could you point me to an article that explains this/has examples with `__import__` function?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to StackOverflow?

Comment: This is funny, I started to write this at SO, but was thinking whether I should post it on programmers.SE instead... I clearly need to look at FAQs...

Comment: You should select one of the below answers as the accepted answer for this question.  IMHO, 9000's answer hits the nail on the head by explaining what Python does with `globals` to determine the module namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The standard implementation does not use its `locals` argument at all, and uses its `globals` only to determine the package context of the `import` statement.

(from [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__))

<sub>I still have no idea how `globals` are used; what global variable can ever affect the way `import` statement works?</sub>

**EDIT:** After looking at `import.c` in Python 2.5 source I found that `__import__` expects to find either `__name__` or `__path__` in `globals` in order to augment import search path relative to path(s) found in one of these variables, in that  order.

Comment: Talk about obtuse.  So basically, instead of passing this massive blob of memory around containing all the globals (assuming Python doesn't do it by reference), one can simple pass a dict with a single key, `"__name__"`, set to the calling module's `__name__` attribute, and Python will work with it.  The Python documentation should be updated with this tidbit of information.

Comment: @Kumba: assume that Python does most everything by reference, except some primitive numeric operations. Dicts are definitely passed by reference. Python 3.3 even introduces an implementation of dicts that share keys, that is, keys are accessed by reference, too. Talk about cache coherence if you want to grumble :)

Comment: Having actually played on (and owning) non-cache-coherent hardware, I can only begin to imagine that nightmare.  Thankfully (or sadly, take your pick), the code I wrote in Python has to run on, at least, Python 2.4.  I've avoided 3.x because I know it completely up-ended the language and a lot of my code probably wouldn't work w/o serious rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

`globals` is used to determine the current context on where the import is being called. For example:

```
"""
/myproject/a/b.py
/myproject/a/foo.py
/myproject/c/d.py
/myproject/c/foo.py
"""

# Which foo gets imported?

import foo #1
foo = __import__('foo') #2
```

They are not the same, since there is no (easy) way on #2 to know from which module the import is being called from. The `__import__` function needs to know which is the current module to actually import the correct `foo`.

Internally on `__import__()`, `globals` is used to get the reference on the current module invoking the import. From the `__import__` [source code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/import.c):

> Return the package that an import is being performed in.  If globals comes
>   from the module foo.bar.bat (not itself a package), this returns the
>   sys.modules entry for foo.bar.  If globals is from a package's **init**.py,
>   the package's entry in sys.modules is returned, as a borrowed reference.

Comment: Let's say that there's `import foo` in `b.py` and `d.py`. How does Python not know which one to import? In case of `b.py`, why would it look for `foo` in `../c`/?

Comment: If there's `import foo` in `/myproject/e.py`, that one should't work. Either `import a.foo` or `import c.foo`. I'm sorry... I can't seem to produce an example which would "cause trouble", could you give me a hint?

Answer (score -2):

> What is there to "interpret" about the module name? What is package context?

When you enter

```
>>> a
```

Python must "interpret" that name.  Is it a global?  Is it a local?

```
>>> def f(x):
...    return x * a
```

Now, `x` is clearly local.  `a` has to be "interpreted".  Global?  Local?

> Why does the example provide globals() and locals() to the function? What happens when I only provide globals()? Or neither?

Try it and see.  Seriously.  It's easier to play with it than it is to ask.

What's important is that things you do at the `>>>` prompt are global.

You'll need to define functions that will create a local context so you can see the differences between global and local.

Comment: The grim^W funny truth is that a module being imported ignores nearly global values of the module that does the import, and `__import__` fully ignores the `locals` parameter. Otherwise, you're correct :)