# how to change relative import search path

Tags: python, import, relative-path

I'm trying to create an auto_import function which is part of a library: the purpose of this to avoid listing `from .x import y` many times in `__init__` files, only do something this `import lib; lib.auto_import(__file__)` <- this would search for python files in that folder where the `__init__` is present and would import all stuff by exec statement (i.e. `exec('from .x import abc')`).

My problem is that, somehow the 'from' statement always tries to import .x from lib directory, even if I change the cwd to the directory where the actual `__init__` file is placed... How should I solve this? How should I change the search dir for `from .` statement?

Structure:

```
$ ls -R
.:
app.py  lib  x

./lib:
__init__.py  auto_import.py

./x:
__init__.py  y

./x/y:
__init__.py  y.py
```

e.g.: `./x/y/__init__.py` contains `import lib; lib.auto_import(__file__)`
auto_import is checking for files in dir of `__file__` and import them with `exec('from .{} import *')` (but this from . is always the lib folder and not the dir of `__file__`, and that is my question, how to change this to dir of `__file__`
Of course the whole stuff is imported in app.py like:

```
import x
print(x.y)
```

Thanks

EDIT1: final auto_import (globals() / gns cannot be avoided )

```
import os, sys, inspect

def auto_import(gns):
  current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
  caller_frame = inspect.getouterframes(current_frame)[1]
  src_file = caller_frame[1]
  for item in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(src_file)):
    item = item.split('.py')[0]

    if item in ['__init__', '__pycache__']:
      continue

    gns.update(__import__(item, gns, locals(), ['*'], 1).__dict__)
```

Comment: Side note: although I have not seen this till the end yet, you might find some useful things [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0).

Comment: Can you give an example of the file/folder structure of your lib? It's quite difficult to follow your question.

Comment: ok, added the structure

Comment: Now the question is clearer. The problem of your approach is that `auto_import` is defined in `lib/auto_import.py` so the context for `exec('from .x import *')` is always `lib/`. Even though you manage to fix the path problem, `lib.auto_import(__file__)` will not import anything to the namespace of `lib.x.y`, because the function locates in another module.

Comment: So, do I need to always manually list the packages of X in the __init__ ??? Even if there is 1-5-10-20-500 etc?? that's funny

Comment: No, there is a better way to do that, I will test it and post an answer later

Comment: I also want to avoid to put the auto_import to all package folders end call them in init file (I guess it would solve my problem about listing packages manually, but imho it would be quite ugly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your approach is that `auto_import` is defined in `lib/auto_import.py` so the context for `exec('from .x import *')` is always `lib/`. Even though you manage to fix the path problem, `lib.auto_import(__file__)` will not import anything to the namespace of `lib.x.y`, because the function locates in another module.

### Use the built-in function `__import__`

Here is the auto_import script:

*myimporter.py*

```
# myimporter.py
def __import_siblings__(gns, lns={}):
  for name in find_sibling_names(gns['__file__']):
    gns.update((k,v) for k,v in __import__(name, gns,lns).__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_'))
import re,os
def find_sibling_names(filename):
  pyfp = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]\w*)\.py$')
  files = (pyfp.match(f) for f in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(filename)))
  return set(f.group(1) for f in files if f)
```

Inside your `lib/x/y/__init__.py`

```
#lib/x/y/__init__.py
from myimporter import __import_siblings__
__import_siblings__(globals())
```

Let's say you have a dummy module that need to be imported to `y`:

```
#lib/x/y/dummy.py
def hello():
  print 'hello'
```

Test it:

```
import x.y
x.y.hello()
```

Please be aware that `from lib import *` is usually a [bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import) because of namespace pollution. Use it with caution.

Refs:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4874342/6238076)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2724260/6238076)

Comment: Working! And almost beautiful, but is it possible to somehow avoid the globals(), locals() pass always to the importer function? I mean, it would be more beautiful if those "code duplications" would not be there always, instead somehow the import function would "calculate" them

Comment: As I see the critical is the globals variable as this still gives fine output:
globals().update(__import__(item, gns, locals(), ['*'], 1).__dict__)

but if i replace that gns with "globals()" then it cannot import

Comment: ok... maybe this is also applicable for the __file__ variable, but still, im courius if you have any idea about that :)

Comment: `gns` is important for the `__import__` function because it uses this namespace to determine the searching path. There is some tricks to avoid passing `globals()` using CPython stack_frame, but that is not standard and only works with CPython.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys` module
With this folder structure:

```
RootDir
    |-- module.py
    |--ChildDir
        |-- main.py
```

Now in `main.py` you can do

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import module
```

A believe there are other hacks, but this is the one I know of and works for my purpose. I am not sure, whether it is the best option to go for some kind of `auto_import` stuff though.

Comment: I don't need another solution, I need the correction for my solution, thanks ;)

Comment: This is not safe because it affect the python interpreter and may accidentally break other libraries.